# Secure offline html5/js-application?

Tags: security, html, cross-platform

I want to develop a cross-plattform application, let's say suitable for desktop (win7/8/Linux) and mobile (win phone/iPhone). It should run in offline-mode and maybe I will chose to go commercial with it. The easiest way to do this is using html5 plus js.

But how can I secure it somehow?

Because there is no online-connection available I can't seperate view from logic. I can't activate it, because every check in js can be bypassed.

Any clues?

Comment: There is no secure way of doing an offline html5 & js application. The client can modify the markup and the js code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Rhodes which is based on Ruby on Rails. As it seems it is running a server on all major smartphone plattforms. It got a sqlite database. I'm going to try that.

Answer (score 1):

For JavaScript you can use obfuscation. This is the easiest and insecure way to hide your code. Search obfuscation tools for JS.
If you want to separate view and logic and hide code you can use Silverlight or Flash, but you'll have problems with iPhone (not supported).
For Silverlight you can use it in offline mode. OS support is also good for SL: win7/8/win phone - completely, Linux - partially(Mono project)

Comment: Obfuscation only slows down someone from doing something malicious.

Comment: I read about obfuscation, but as you write - it is insecure. I had a thought about mono, too, but as far as I can see it, I have to pay for mono touch which I do not want.